# Return variables from mixin with Stylus

Tags: css, sass, stylus

Is it possible to apply variables to the local scope from a mixin or function? For example:

```
.hello-world
    get-variables(bar);
    content: $foo;
```

Will output to:

```
.hello-world
    content: 'bar';
```

Because the get-variables mixin applied a variable named $foo to the local scope.

Is this possible in Stylus? If not, is it possible with Sass?

Comment: What is the end result you're trying to achieve by this? There may be a better way to go about it. Variable scope exists for a reason, and attempting to subvert that seems like bad practice to me.

Comment: what's wrong with `.hello-world($foo)` `content: $foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing I don't think it's possible to return variables from a mixin or function in Stylus.

For example:

```
val = green

foo()
    val = red
    return val

.foo
    foo()
    color val
```

Returns:

```
.foo {
    color: green;
}
```

In SASS however this:

```
$val: green

@mixin foo 
    $val: red

.foo
    @include foo
    color: $val
```

Will return:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

In Stylus however you can assign the result of a function to a variable which may or may not give you the result you are looking for.

```
val = foo()
content val
```